# Can separate codebases be used for Installable and Instant versions of an app

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-instant-apps, codebase

I have a large game app that uses external resources like Firebase database I'd like to have an Instant App option for on Google Play. So far the most complete tutorial I've found to do this is the Codelabs one here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0. Unfortunately they use a 'hello world' app built with Koltin, and during the enormous 20+ step conversion process to turn the app into separate modules, before even dealing with features, you run into cryptic Kotlin errors like 'Gradle DSL method not found: '1.3.41()'.

I was wondering if it was possible to use two separate applications, one for the large installable app and one for the bare bones instant app, packaging them together or uploading them separately. It appears the 'Android Instant App' tab on the Google Play Console just replaces whatever you uploaded in the 'Release dashboard' tab, as it requires the same package name and incremented version number.

I had some hopes as the first sentence of Chapter 4 of Codelabs's involved tutorial starts with 'When supporting Google Play Instant you can and absolutely should use the same codebase for your instant app and your installable app'. This suggests there would be the option of separate codebases, which would not involve breaking your project up into 'Installed', 'Instant' and 'Base' modules and miraculously not breaking the app in the process.

Answer (score 1):

The codelab you’re referring to uses an outdated structure of Google Play Instant: com.android.feature and com.android.instantapp plugins are being deprecated since Android Gradle plugin 3.4.0 in a favor of instant-enabled App Bundles (more on [Android Developer blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/google-play-instant-feature-plugin.html)).

Check out [Create an instant-enabled app bundle](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle) documentation and [codelabs](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#additional-resources).